# Why does AngularjS route fails with 1.26.x but works with 1.0.8?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This sample works as it is-
https://github.com/shyamseshadri/angularjs-book/tree/master/chapter2/aMail when it uses AngularJS version 1.0.8. But if the version is changed to latest - 1.2.16, the program fails to load the views. Any reason why?

Comment: Angular routing is now a dependency, did you load it?

Comment: @elclanrs, other than including angular-route.js anything else to be done? 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>-->

Comment: Adding ngRoute reference as dependency in module should fix it.

var aMailServices = angular.module('AMail', ['ngRoute']);